# Ignoring collision and (second) pre-image resistance, what makes a cryptographic hash function strong?

Tags: passwords, hash, brute-force, password-cracking

With regards to resistance against dictionary and brute-force attacks to "crack" hashes containing passwords, what determines the resistance of a cryptographic hash function? Since collision resistance is not important for password storing, and, as far as I know, all the popular hash functions are resistant enough to pre-image and second pre-image attacks to make it an infeasible approach, I guess those factors don't really matter.

The first thing that crosses my mind is the amount of computation needed to calculate the hash (is there a word for this?) - the higher amount the longer it's going to take. Is there anything else? Bit-length? Is bit-length and "computation amount" somehow correlated?

Comment: Far from a complete answer: an additional measure can be the amount of memory needed to compute the hash (to prevent parallelization to some extent). The number of bits is **theoretically** relevant if your goal is to find a matching plaintext (more bits, more possible outputs: on average more attempts to find a matching plaintext), but not that relevant if your goal is to find the plaintext initially used (more bits increase the chances that a matching plaintext is in fact the one initially used). This is, however, only relevant if the attacker can check *many* hashes -- thus "theortically".

Answer (score 2):

Since the context of this appears to be password cracking, and cryptographic hashes are unsuitable for storing passwords, the simple answer is just "your question is irrelevant".

A good cryptographic hash function has a number of basic design goals:

- It should be computationally feasible to compute a hash H(x) for some input value x.
- Changing one bit of the input should change all output bits with a probability of 50%.
- Given only the hash output, it should not be computationally feasible to recover any information about the input (aside from generic attacks like rainbow tables).
- Given an input x<sub>1</sub>, it should not be computationally feasible to find another input x<sub>2</sub> which satisfies the condition H(x<sub>1</sub>) == H(x<sub>2</sub>), i.e. it should be hard to find collisions.

While these basic goals are certainly useful, they don't really cover the full requirements of a good password storage function. To answer your question more specifically: large or controllable computational cost is most certainly not a feature of most "ordinary" cryptographic hash functions.

A good password storage function, alongside all of the above, should have these additional design goals:

- It should not be deterministic, i.e. two equal passwords for different users (or other entities) should not result in the same output hash.
- It should implement some form of defense against precomputation attacks (e.g. rainbow tables)
- It should be computationally expensive to brute-force the original input for all but trivial and common dictionary inputs. This is usually controlled by implementing a cost value, which allows for scaling of performance.
- There should not be a way to produce more than negligible performance gains using time/space tradeoffs.
- The performance of the function should be roughly linear across all architectures, to avoid acceleration by GPUs, FPGAs, etc. perhaps excluding specifically-designed silicon.

Some of these goals are similar to those implemented by key-derivation functions (KDFs) such as PBKDF2, but again these functions are not *designed* for password storage, and have instead been appropriated for such uses.

While there are currently only a few designs that implement all of the above, it is a relatively new field, so future works is expected. As a matter of interest, the current state-of-the-art for password storage, as per [PHC](https://password-hashing.net/index.html), is [Argon](https://password-hashing.net/submissions/specs/Argon-v3.pdf).

Comment: "... cryptographic hashes are unsuitable for storing passwords.. "  
But in practice it's the most common thing to use, no?

Comment: @tsorn There are lots of people using bad security practices out there. It's the whole reason I have a job in the first place.

Comment: Well then, what are you really saying? Ignoring the requirement of a salt (a password storage function _has_ to be deterministic, no?), the difference between a "password storage function" and a cryptographic hash function is higher or controlled computational cost and a implementation that avoids architecture-specific acceleration?

Comment: @tsorn Yes, essentially, which is something that cryptographic hash functions do not provide.

Comment: Nitpick in the last bullet of your cryptographic hash design goals: What you describe is a second preimage, not a collision. For a collision, the attacker is not *given* an input x, instead the attacker finds any such x and x' where h(x)==h(x').